# compare rows between two ids with in the same table and insert the missing row for that id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have a table which has structure mentioned below 
let's say table name -> tab1

```
id   c1     c2    c3         c4
1    a      b   01-02-18     c          row1
1    o      b   01-02-18     c          row2
1    a      b   04-05-16     c          row3
1    n      g   01-02-18     d          row4
2    a      b   01-02-18     c          row5
```

So i want to insert id 1 rows to id 2. As data for row1 and row5 is same for column c1,c2,c3,c4 so i want to skip row1 to be inserted for id 2 .

Table should look like this

```
id   c1     c2    c3         c4
1    a      b   01-02-18     c          row1
1    o      b   01-02-18     c          row2
1    a      b   04-05-16     c          row3
1    n      g   01-02-18     d          row4
2    a      b   01-02-18     c          row5
2    o      b   01-02-18     c          row6
2    a      b   04-05-16     c          row7
2    n      g   01-02-18     d          row8
```

i have written this query but doesn't give me the expected result

for selecting the unique record based on column :

```
select Count(*) FROM tab1 A
WHERE   Not EXISTS 
(select * from  tab1  B where  A.c1 = B.c1 AND A.c2 = B.c2 AND A.c3= B.c3 
AND A.c4 = B.c4 
and B.id=2 )and A.id = 1;
```

for inserting the  records

```
insert into rsk_mdl_sec_map_ts
select '2', c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM tab1 A
WHERE   Not EXISTS 
(select * from  tab1  B where  A.c1 = B.c1 AND A.c2 = B.c2 AND A.c3= B.c3 
AND A.c4 = B.c4 
and B.id=2 )and A.id = 1;
```

can anyone help what is wrong in this or suggest me some other approach to achieve the same . Thanks

Comment: What is the result that you get when you execute the `INSERT` query you have written?

Comment: the issue is with the select query is not giving expected result so i didn't executed the insert query . First i need to fix this select query then only i can move to next step select * FROM tab1 A WHERE Not EXISTS (select * from tab1 B where A.c1 = B.c1 AND A.c2 = B.c2 AND A.c3= B.c3 AND A.c4 = B.c4 and B.id=2 )and A.id = 1;

Comment: I excuted the query you mention and seems to work as expected. Can you post the output that you get?

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @GiorgosBetsos  in my real time query i just used truc to compare the dates and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

First build a query that pick rows which should be insered and omits those that already exist as `id=2` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 t1
WHERE id = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'anything' FROM tab1 t2
    WHERE t1.c1=t2.c1
      AND t1.c2=t2.c2
      AND t1.c3=t2.c3
      AND t1.c4=t2.c4
      AND id = 2
)

| ID | C1 | C2 |                    C3 | C4 |
|----|----|----|-----------------------|----|
|  1 |  o |  b | 2018-01-02 00:00:00.0 |  c |
|  1 |  a |  b | 2016-04-05 00:00:00.0 |  c |
|  1 |  n |  g | 2018-01-02 00:00:00.0 |  d |
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d66fc/4

---

Next, use INSERT ... SELECT .... command, just put INSERT above the SELECT command, and use `2` constant as ID, and DISTINCT clause to remove possible duplicates:

```
INSERT into tab1( id, c1, c2, c3, c4 )

SELECT DISTINCT 2, c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM tab1 t1
WHERE id = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'anything' FROM tab1 t2
    WHERE t1.c1=t2.c1
      AND t1.c2=t2.c2
      AND t1.c3=t2.c3
      AND t1.c4=t2.c4
      AND id = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your test data, we can do the following cross join - which will give us each ID combined with all rows that have id 1:

```
 select 
  T2.id
, T1.c1
, T1.c2
, T1.c3
, T1.c4
from (
  select *
  from tab1
  where id = 1 
) T1, ( select unique id from tab1 ) T2
;

-- result
ID  C1  C2  C3         C4  
1   a   b   01-FEB-18  c   
1   o   b   01-FEB-18  c   
1   a   b   04-MAY-18  c   
1   n   g   01-FEB-18  d   
2   a   b   01-FEB-18  c   
2   o   b   01-FEB-18  c   
2   a   b   04-MAY-18  c   
2   n   g   01-FEB-18  d
```

Then, use the MINUS operator and insert all resulting rows.

```
insert into tab1 ( id, c1, c2, c3, c4 )
(
  select 
    T2.id
  , T1.c1
  , T1.c2
  , T1.c3
  , T1.c4
  from (
    select *
    from tab1
    where id = 1 
  ) T1, ( select unique id from tab1 ) T2
)
minus                -- do not insert existing rows
select * from tab1   
;

3 rows inserted.
```

Tab1 now contains:

```
select * from tab1 ;
ID  C1  C2  C3         C4  
1   a   b   01-FEB-18  c   
1   o   b   01-FEB-18  c   
1   a   b   04-MAY-18  c   
1   n   g   01-FEB-18  d   
2   a   b   01-FEB-18  c   
2   a   b   04-MAY-18  c   
2   n   g   01-FEB-18  d   
2   o   b   01-FEB-18  c
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2c5405f060d2fb0cf774fe0db88c770) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use MERGE:

```
merge into tab1
using ( select 2 as id, c1, c2, c3, c4 
       from tab1
       where id = 1 -- optional
    ) q
on (q.id = tab1.id
    and q.c1 = tab1.c1
    and q.c2 = tab1.c2
    and q.c3 = tab1.c3
    and q.c4 = tab1.c4)
when not matched then
    insert values (q.id, q.c1, q.c2, q.c3, q.c4)
;
```

This solution will work provided `tab1(id, c1, c2, c3, c4)` defines a set of unique rows.

Here is [a demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eadfc/1).

Answer (score 0):

simply create a temporary table **TMP_TABLE** to do **full join**

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TABLE AS SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tab1 ) a,
(SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM tab1 ) b
```